# Delete records using sql ,if it is greater than certain number with an unit attached to it (eg 3M or 3cm)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-delete

let a table be 'hotel' , with a column :

| hotel_worth |
| --- |
| 15M |
| 4M |
| 8M |
| 3M |
| 1M |
| 2M |
| 11M |

how do i delete the records in the table using sql ,where worth is greater than 3M.

Comment: By not storing 'M' in the first place

Comment: @Strawberry this is  a test practise qn and that is exactly what i wouldve done too. but i need to do this with the 'M'. and with sql alone.thats the question.

Comment: Are there values other than "M"?

Comment: Well I would give the points to the answer that said "Don't store 'M', or, if storing 'M',  don't bother with a relational database."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `WHERE` clause of the `DELETE` statement you can convert the string to a numeric value by adding `0`:

```
DELETE FROM hotel
WHERE hotel_worth + 0 > 3
```

If you want to delete only rows with the suffix `M` (if there are other suffixes also) add:

```
AND RIGHT(hotel_worth, 1) = 'M'
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using:

```
DELETE FROM price 
WHERE SUBSTR(`hotel_worth`, 1, LENGTH(`hotel_worth`) - 1) + 0 > 3
```

Explanation: the `substr` function :

```
SUBSTR(`hotel_worth`, 1, LENGTH(`hotel_worth`) - 1)
```

retrieves the data of the column excluding the last character ie (from 10M to 10), then the + 0 to it converts it to int.

So the `> 3` comparison at the end basically means selecting data that are greater than 3M.

Comment: There is no need to take the substring and then add 0. You can do it directly to the string value of the column.

Comment: @forpas oh i tried that and thought it didnt work since i got Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '15M' and so on . so i didnt bother to check  the table , my bad. thanks urs is short . but what does + 0 do to an '3M'.and what does the numeric value look like , i thought it turned a "3" to a 3 .

Comment: When adding 0 to a string MySql does implicit conversion of the string to a number. The resulting number is the starting part of the string that can be converted to a number. So 3M becomes 3 and 100M becomes 100.